# Cocoa auto-resizable window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

How can I make my NSWindow with NSTabView smoothly resize when user clicks a tab? I want it to like "System Preferances" application: window changes its size according to content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use NSWindow's setFrame:animated: method. If you want to resize the window down, make sure you decrease the y coordinate of the origin by the same amount you increase the size of the window. To also resize the views in the window, make sure you set up their autoresizing properties correctly.

```
NSWindow *window;
CGFloat widthChange, heightChange;

NSRect frame = [window frame];
frame.size.width += widthChange;
frame.size.height += heightChange;
frame.origin.y -= heightChange;
[window setFrame:frame animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can't this be done in Interface Builder using percentages?  I seem to remember that from awhile ago, but may be wrong.

Comment: I believe IB stores information about the window's frame as percentages so that it can look good on different sized screens, but there is no way to have it change the window's size when you change tabs. You have to do it programmatically.