# how to make a tab window slide from top in mac using qt?

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt

I m designing a settings windows in mac using qt with tabbuttons and qmaindwindow.

I want to display a tab window to be slided from top when its corresponding tab button in qmainwindow toolbar is clicked.
Same as mac system preferences or vlc preferences sliding window action.

Hope someone know the direction to be headed to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Sliding action is not working. Event I tried QDialog for each tab in qmainwindow.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Ui_windo(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setObjectName("windo")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.toolbuttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
        self.toolbuttonGroup.setObjectName("toolbuttonGroup")
        self.toolbuttonGroup.setExclusive(True)
        self.button0 = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.button1 = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.button2 = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.tabbutton(self.button0, 'button0')
        self.tabbutton(self.button1, 'button1')
        self.tabbutton(self.button2, 'button2')

        _toolBar = self.addToolBar('test')
        _toolBar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        _toolBar.addWidget(self.button0)
        _toolBar.addWidget(self.button1)
        _toolBar.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True);

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.button0, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.dialog0)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.button1, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.dialog1)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.button2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.dialog2)

    def dialog0(self):
        self._dialog0 = QtGui.QDialog()
        self._button0=QtGui.QPushButton(self._dialog0)
        self._button0.setText('Main dialog 0')
        self._dialog0.setModal(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._dialog0)

    def dialog1(self):
        self._dialog1 = QtGui.QDialog()
        self._button1=QtGui.QPushButton(self._dialog1)
        self._button1.setText('I m from dialog1')
        self._dialog1.setModal(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._dialog1)

    def dialog2(self):
        self._dialog2 = QtGui.QDialog()
        self._button2=QtGui.QPushButton(self._dialog2)
        self._button2.setText('I m from dialog2')
        self._dialog2.setModal(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._dialog2)

    def tabbutton(self, tabButton, text):
        self.toolbuttonGroup.addButton(tabButton)
        tabButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        tabButton.setText(text)
        tabButton.setObjectName(text)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        tabButton.setIcon(icon)
        tabButton.setCheckable(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_windo()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

use QDialog with parent set to window from which it has to "slide down". It will do it "automagicaly"

Comment: tab window didnt slide though i used 'qdialog' as per ur suggestion. Added the code i tried in pyqt. May be u can find the reason wer it lags.

Comment: @user971306 Try replacing `self.setCentralWidget(self._dialogX)` by `self._dialogX.exec_()` and add self to the constructor calls (`self._dialogX = QtGui.QDialog(self)` ), you can remove the call to `setModal`, as `exec_()` takes already care of that.

Comment: @alexisdm Tab window is opened as seperate dialog instead of a tab for the qmainwindow when setCentralWidget function call is removed.

Comment: @user971306 I can be wrong, but it doesn't appear that Qt handles tab window size animation when you change a tab, only top level `QDialog` (see [this QtQuaterly article](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html) ), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830873/cocoa-auto-resizable-window) suggests that you have to do it (almost) manually even with Cocoa.